# Setting default date format for datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I keep track of various dates. So I end up using datepicker through jquery anywhere from 10-200 times. I want to set the default for all cases of datepicker to the 'yy-mm-dd' - but I can't seem to figure out how to set that?

Answer (score 26):

> I end up using datepicker through jquery anywhere from 10-200 times.

I'm assuming you're calling `datepicker()` separately for each input, probably by `id`. There's no need for that.

Use a `class` as a hook on your input:

```
<input class="my-datepicker">
```

Then call `datepicker` on elements with that class with your default configuration:

```
$('.my-datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

When you need a different configuration, use/assign a different class name.

You can also use [`setDefaults`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.setDefaults) (probably what you're looking for):

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

Answer (score -7):

Go to the file `jquery.ui.datepicker.js`.

```
function Datepicker()
{
     dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
}
```

Change it to the format you prefer. It will change the format for your whole website.